# Taxonomy fetch with slug in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can we fetch a custom post type, with the help of a taxonomy slug, using a `SELECT` WordPress query?

Comment: "post" is not custom post type. It's default post type.
Could you please elaborate your question neatly?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `SELECT` to fetch custom post with the help of taxonomy slug.

WordPress provides us [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function to retrieve a list of posts matching given criteria.

```
$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //-1 is to retrieve all posts.
        'post_type' => 'my_custom_post', //specify your custom post.
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy' //taxonomy on which you are going to find posts
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WP_Query to fetch posts what you need. In your case the query could be like this:

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'my_custom_post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_custom_taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'my_custom_taxonomy_slug',
        ),
    ) );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Show Posts ...
    endwhile;

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

[Click here](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query) to read documentation for it.